# Add tab to page via api returns list but pinging the request via browser returns true

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, tabs, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am trying to add a tab to a page, facebooks graph api states a request with the following params should be made:

```
/PAGE_ID/tabs?app_id=MY_APP_ID&method=post&access_token=PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN
```

When i use it with FB.api:

```
FB.api("/PAGE_ID/tabs?app_id=MY_APP_ID&method=post&access_token=PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN", function(response) {

});
```

Response is just a list of tabs on the page, yet when i go to the brwoser and enter the same thing:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/PAGE_ID/tabs?app_id=MY_APP_ID&method=post&access_token=PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN
```

Same request only manually it returns true and adds a tab.

**NOTE:**
I have page access token and a page id as instructed **[here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/#tabs)**, sub section "Create".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Response is just a list of tabs on the page

That’s what you get for a GET request to `/pageid/tabs`.

So this indicates that your parameter `method=post` is not recognized correctly, therefor no POST but just a GET request is made … and you get the list of tabs of the page.

Use this instead, then it should work:

```
FB.api("/PAGE_ID/tabs?app_id=MY_APP_ID&access_token=PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN",
  "post",
  function(response) { console.log(response); }
);
```

Telling FB.api what method to use is done here via the second parameter, by just passing the method name as a string, `"post"`.

Just tested this using a page and app of mine – it just returns `true` in the console as expected, and the app is installed as page tab app on the page afterwards.

Comment: Thank you, looks like facebook requires this action with the "post" param as you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try out this code:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:fb="https://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
  <head>
    <title>My Add to Page Dialog Page</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id='fb-root'></div>
<script src='http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js'></script>
<p><a onclick='addToPage(); return false;'>Add to Page</a></p>
<p id='msg'></p>

<script> 
  FB.init({appId: "YOUR_APP_ID", status: true, cookie: true});

  function addToPage() {

    // calling the API ...
    var obj = {
      method: 'pagetab',
      redirect_uri: 'REDIRECT_URI',
    };

    FB.ui(obj);
  }

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thats not what i am looking for, this will open a dialog and request the user to add a tab for a page he owns, i want to make an api call which will add the tab to a page (i have page access token and page id) so i have all the permissions i need to do such action, please read my description in the answer.